# new vs old customers sql

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, aggregate-functions, date-arithmetic

I am trying to get new customer's vs returning customers and for this I have to create multiple tables. Is there a better way to aggregate the data shown like below:

[image: FORMAT PICTURE]

my SQL code looks like below:

```
---- ALL INDIVIDUALS WHO PURCHASED IN CURRENT WEEK---------
CREATE TABLE PURCHASES_FEB_WK2 AS (Select DISTINCT INDIVIDUAL_ID
from DM_OWNER.TRANSACTION_DETAIL_MV
WHERE BRAND_ORG_CODE = 'BRAND'
and is_merch = 1
and currency_code = 'USD'
AND LINE_ITEM_AMT_TYPE_CD = 'S'
AND TRUNC(TXN_DATE) BETWEEN '10-FEB-19' AND '16-FEB-19')


----------MINIMUM PURCHASE DATE OF ALL CUSTOMERS------------
Create table feb_wk2_min as
Select distinct Individual_ID, MIN(TRANSACTION_DATE) as FIRST_TRANSACTION
from dm_owner.transaction_mv
WHERE BRAND_ORG_CODE = 'BRAND'
and transaction_type_code in ('PR','EP')
group by individual_ID;


------- NEW CUSTOMERS FOR THE WEEK---------
Select Count(distinct B.INDIVIDUAL_ID) 
from PURCHASES_FEB_WK2 A
JOIN FEB_WK2_MIN B ON A.INDIVIDUAL_ID = B.INDIVIDUAL_ID
where FIRST_TRANSACTION between '10-FEB-19' and '16-FEB-19'


---- ALL RETURNING CUSTOMERS
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT INDIVIDUAL_ID)
FROM PURCHASES_FEB_WK2 
WHERE INDIVIDUAL_ID IN (SELECT INDIVIDUAL_ID FROM DM_OWNER.TRANSACTION_DETAIL_MV WHERE TRUNC(TXN_DATE) < '10-FEB-19' AND BRAND_ORG_CODE = 'BRAND' AND IS_MERCH = 1 AND line_item_amt_type_cd = 'S' AND STATUS = 'A')





-------NEW CUSTOMERS DOLLAR_VALUE_US------
SELECT SUM(DOLLAR_VALUE_US) FROM DM_OWNER.TRANSACTION_DETAIL_MV 
WHERE INDIVIDUAL_ID IN (Select distinct B.INDIVIDUAL_ID 
from PURCHASES_FEB_WK2 A
JOIN FEB_WK2_MIN B ON A.INDIVIDUAL_ID = B.INDIVIDUAL_ID
where FIRST_TRANSACTION between '10-FEB-19' and '16-FEB-19')
AND BRAND_ORG_CODE = 'BRAND'
and is_merch = 1
and currency_code = 'USD'
AND LINE_ITEM_AMT_TYPE_CD = 'S'
AND TRUNC(TXN_DATE) BETWEEN '10-FEB-19' AND '16-FEB-19'




-------RETURNING CUSTOMERS DOLLAR_VALUE_US------
SELECT SUM(DOLLAR_VALUE_US) FROM DM_OWNER.TRANSACTION_DETAIL_MV 
WHERE INDIVIDUAL_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT INDIVIDUAL_ID
FROM PURCHASES_FEB_WK2 
WHERE INDIVIDUAL_ID IN (SELECT INDIVIDUAL_ID FROM DM_OWNER.TRANSACTION_DETAIL_MV WHERE TRUNC(TXN_DATE) < '10-FEB-19' AND BRAND_ORG_CODE = 'BRAND' AND IS_MERCH = 1 AND line_item_amt_type_cd = 'S' AND STATUS = 'A'))
AND BRAND_ORG_CODE = 'BRAND'
and is_merch = 1
and currency_code = 'USD'
AND LINE_ITEM_AMT_TYPE_CD = 'S'
AND TRUNC(TXN_DATE) BETWEEN '10-FEB-19' AND '16-FEB-19'
```

To get the quantity and the count of order, I am replacing the sum (dollar_value_us) with count of distinct orders and sum of quantity. Is there an easy way to pivot and combine this code so that I can just copy paste the data in the format (picture attached) I have provided.

Comment: First, there is no reason that you need separate tables.  Second, I'm sure your code is way more complicated than it needs to be.  This is why you want to describe your problem clearly, provide sample data, and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the problem is that I am trying to get the new customers for the current period from the transactions table who have not transacted before ever. Then I am calculating the repeating customers who have transacted in the current period but also in the past. For that I have created 2 tables purchases which shows everyone who has transacted in the current period and min table in which there is the first purchase date of all the customers. then I need to know the dollar spend, qty, order count, and count of  those individuals based on new or returning.

Comment: @DaveS can you read it now, or do you want me to go a font smaller.

Comment: I must say that the very fact that you have a table named PURCHASES_WK_FEB2 (separate tables for the same data, simply different time periods) is indicative of a fatally flawed design.  As @GordonLinoff said, there is no reason for multiple tables here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, I understand that you want to split the customers into two groups : customers that had their first transactions during the period should be separated from thoses who had transactions before. For each group, you want to count the number of customers and sum the value of the transactions.

NB : your sql code does not show hot to compute `qty` and `count_of_orders`, so I left it apart (but this will likely follow the same logic).

Given this sample data:

```
INDIVIDUAL_ID | DOLLAR_VALUE_US | TXN_DATE  | RAND_ORG_CODE | IS_MERCH | CURRENCY_CODE | LINE_ITEM_AMT_TYPE_CD
------------: | --------------: | :-------- | :------------ | -------: | :------------ | :--------------------
            1 |              10 | 01-FEB-19 | BRAND         |        1 | USD           | S                    
            1 |              10 | 10-FEB-19 | BRAND         |        1 | USD           | S                    
            1 |              10 | 15-FEB-19 | BRAND         |        1 | USD           | S                    
            1 |              10 | 28-FEB-19 | BRAND         |        1 | USD           | S                    
            2 |              11 | 11-FEB-19 | BRAND         |        1 | USD           | S                    
            2 |              11 | 12-FEB-19 | BRAND         |        1 | USD           | S                    
            3 |              11 | 12-FEB-19 | BRAND         |        1 | USD           | S
```

Considering week range from February 10th to 16th included, customer `1` is a returning customer with 2 transactions in the window, and customers `2` and `3` are new customers with respectively 2 and 1 transactions. You would expect the following output:

```
TYPE_OF_CUSTOMER    | COUNT_OF_CUSTOMERS | SUM_DOLLAR_VALUE_US
:------------------ | -----------------: | ------------------:
New Customers       |                  2 |                  33
Returning Customers |                  1 |                  20
```

---

To solve this, you need to set up several levels of aggregation. First, use window function `MIN() OVER()` to recover the date of the first transaction of each customer. Then, filter on the anlaysis period, split customers into new/returning groups, and aggregate the money spent. Finally, aggregate all results together.

Query:

```
SELECT
    DECODE(is_new, 1, 'New Customers', 'Returning Customers') type_of_customer,
    COUNT(individual_id) count_of_customers,
    SUM(dollar_value_us) sum_dollar_value_us
FROM (
    SELECT
        individual_id,
        SUM(dollar_value_us) dollar_value_us,
        CASE WHEN MIN(txn_date) = min_txn_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END is_new
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            individual_id, 
            dollar_value_us,
            txn_date,
            MIN(txn_date) OVER(PARTITION BY individual_id) min_txn_date   
        FROM transaction_detail_mv   
        WHERE 
            rand_org_code = 'BRAND'
            AND is_merch = 1
            AND currency_code = 'USD'
            AND line_item_amt_type_cd = 'S'
    ) t
    WHERE 
        txn_date >= TO_DATE('10-02-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
        AND txn_date < TO_DATE('17-02-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
    GROUP BY
        individual_id,
        min_txn_date
) x GROUP BY is_new
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a62de415fc752bef2152412d49baec5f)** demonstrates each step of the computation.

Comment: Hello, thank for this. the qty and orders are separate columns in the transaction_detail_mv table.

Comment: @SomiyaL : ok, you should be able to adapt the query I provided you with. You can use the db fiddle link to add the columns to the schema, add sample data and play around with the queries.

Comment: Hello I tried to use the db fiddle, I was not able to get the count of orders and sum of quantity as a column header in the final table. :(

I added qty and transaction_number to the table you created on db fiddle

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e92d3d8baed95d1243ffb20e2d75641b

Comment: @SomiyaL: I [updated the fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e7fbb96a2d269e37d1436e178d523066) to take in account the additional columns.

Comment: Hello @GMB, thank you so much !! you are a genius ! I just had another question, I wanted to divide the customers into male and female. There is gender field in another table (sum_indiv) and I wanted it to look Like below format:

Age Range Female Count Male Count Unknown Count
18-24   
25-32   
33-39   
40-46   
47-53   
54-60   
61+   
<18   
Null
 its a table with age range, female count, male count in the headers and age ranges on the left side.